# 'if not for': Is this use correct?

Tags: meaning

> [[3rd last para:]](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/without-prejudice/201403/the-meat-paradox-loving-exploiting-animals) ... Two recent studies demonstrate that right-wing adherents consume more meat and exploit animals more for two main reasons: (a) they push back against the threat that vegetarianism and veganism supposedly pose to traditions and cultural practice, and (b) they feel more entitled to consume animals given human “superiority” (Dhont & Hodson, 2014). You read that correctly: those on the left would not differ from those on the right in meat consumption **[if not](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/38290/8712) for** the latter’s relatively higher sense of threat from animal-rights ideologies and their sense of human superiority (and thus entitlement). Ideology, is [ Typo: This should be 'it'   ] seems, creeps into the very foods we eat (see Loughan et al., in press).

How should **if not for** be analysed/decomposed/parsed?  I tried substituting 'perhaps even' for **if not**, but this seems wrong, because I'm guessing that the sentence explains that 'those on the left .... in meat consumption', absent 'the latter's relatively higher sense of threat...'?

Comment: The meaning is different, as you note.  Here it effectively means "except for" or "if the following did not exist."

Answer (score 1):

Again, here, as in your other question, **if not** shortens ***if*** + pronoun + verb + **not.**

...***if*** (it was) **not** for the latter's...